# To obtain logs from the last 5 months that show jobs that have failed

Tags: sql-server, jobs

I am trying to get information regarding the failed jobs for the last 4-5 months as a log file or any type of data. The jobs are run on the (MS)SQL server and are sql jobs.

My friend told me that the log files generated by the server get deleted every time the server is rebooted.

Is there any way to obtain this information.

Comment: mysql or (MS)SQL-Server?

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question. I removed the database tags as it is unclear which one you are actually using. Please add the tag of *only* the database you are actually using

Comment: @Jens (MS)SQL-Server.

Comment: @JohnConde Okay. I thought since the jobs were SQL jobs its only right that i add sql. I have added sql-server back as the server on which the jobs are on is a sql server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No job history disappears when your server restarts,
maybe you was told about SQL Server error log that initialize at every restart,
but even previous error log does not disappear.
In every case you can check your failed job this way:

```
select j.name,
       j.description,
       h.*
from msdb.dbo.sysjobs j join msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory h 
        on j.job_id = h.job_id 
where h.run_status = 0 -- failed
order by h.run_date;
```

You can check out how many history rows are preserved choosing SQL Server Agent Properties History tab.

Comment: It just gives me failed jobs from the past 2 days. Is there anyway to get the failed jobs that are earlier than that.

Comment: Did you check the limit for job history entries in sql server agent properties?
Based on this limit the history was purged, now you can change this limit for future use 
and you can also restore msdb database backups for the periods you are interested in and find missing enties there

Comment: Yes I did, I haven't set it to remove agent history. That is why is was surprised.

Comment: What you found is the default setting and it's better to purge by default than not to purge, in case any other DBA that has no idea of job history purging necessity, one day msdb could explose if someone had 100 jobs and every job executed every minute or so

Comment: oh so there would be no way to gather the data about failed jobs from the SQL server then?

Comment: I wrote you how to do this, you can restore msdb backups and find the old job history in msdb at 2 days ago, at 4 days ago, ecc. You do backup your msdb (as well as master), doesn't you?

Comment: Yes sir! Thank You for the info